# Scaling elements like an image

Tags: html, css

When I for example have an image in  :

```
<img src="10px_image.png" alt="Some image" style="width: 100%" />
```

Its height automatically gets scaled according to width the image gets (you can see that when you resize the browser window for example). Is there any way to do the same with other elements in html ?

Comment: Do you want a proportional scaling?

Comment: see HTML5 [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

Answer (score 5):

### Solution #1

You could use the new css viewport units `vw`, `vh` etc to pull this off.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/h4xrE/4/)**

```
div
{
    width: 40vw;
    height: 20vw;
    background: pink;
}
```

> CSS3 has some new values for sizing things relative to the current
>   viewport size: vw, vh, and vmin.
>   One unit on any of the three values is 1% of the viewport axis.
>   "Viewport" == browser window size == window object. If the viewport is
>   40cm wide, 1vw == 0.4cm.
>
> 1vw = 1% of viewport width 1vh = 1% of viewport height 1vmin = 1vw or
>   1vh, whichever is smaller 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger ([css-tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/))

[**Support**](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units): IE 9+, Firefox 19+, Chrome 20+, Safari 6+

Reference: **[w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)**, **[mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)**

---

### Solution #2

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zC2xA/1/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer r4x3">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
/* container defines margins and width */
.container {
    margin: 60px 120px 0;
}

/* outer container will define aspect ratio */
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.outer.r4x3 {
    padding-top: 75%; /* "height" will be 3/4 of width */
}
/* inner container positioned absolutely and holds content */
.outer .inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    outline: 1px solid grey;
    background: pink;
}
```

Comment: Well it's something but the method's browser support is very poor and I would need the exact proportions of the element every single time... Plus it's always relative to the browser window.

Comment: @user2394156 - I updated my answer - both solutions now answer your question

Answer (score 0):

here is a trick which is actually for responsive video and Iframes to maintain aspect ratio but it work on other things as well... http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos